# An example of almost periodic function

Tags: limits, analysis, special-functions, almost-periodic-functions

"**I need a continuous almost periodic function $f(x)$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists. But this function should not be constant, which is a trivial example**."

**Definition of almost periodic function:**
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlmostPeriodicFunction.html

We take the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}$, i.e., $d(x,y)=|x-y|$.

**Examples of almost periodic functions:**
(but $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)$ does not exist) $$f(t)=\frac{\cos t}{2+\cos\sqrt2t}\ ,\quad f(t)=\sin2\pi t+ \sin2\pi t\sqrt2 ~.$$

On the other hand, page 69, paragraph 4 of the article http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102812425 says the following:

"Once Bohr established his fundamental theorem, he was able to
show that any continuous almost periodic function is the limit of a
uniformly convergent sequence of trigonometric polynomials. This is
the main result of his second paper. The converse of this result was also true."

Since we know that for every non-constant periodic function $g(x)$ (or trigonometric function), $g(x)$ does not exist as $x$ tends to infinity, can we conclude (from uniform convergence) that almost periodic functions also have the same property?

Thanks your help.

Comment: Probably the OP means function almost periodic in Bohr sense (approximable uniformly by a sequence of generalized trigonometric polynomials).

Comment: I saw your meta question with [a comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12707/why-are-bounties-non-refundable-even-there-is-no-answer#comment49721_12707) that suggests that you value your time. Please also value the time of others: make your question unambiguous by specifying the definition of "almost periodic". There are [several inequivalent definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_periodic_function). If you improve the question, you might not need to put a bounty at all.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions and your time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The     [definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlmostPeriodicFunction.html) quickly implies that a nonconstant almost periodic function $f$ cannot have a limit at infinity. Indeed, pick $a,b$ such that $f(a)\ne f(b)$. Fix  $\epsilon>0$ such that $$|f(a)-f(b)|>3\epsilon\tag{1}$$ Let $\ell=\ell(\epsilon) $ be as in the definition.  Then for every   integer $n$ there exists $\tau_n\in [n, n+\ell]$ such that 
$$|f(a+\tau_n)-f(a)|<\epsilon,\qquad |f(b+\tau_n)-f(b)|<\epsilon\tag{2}$$
It follows from (1) and (2) that 
$$|f(a+\tau_n)-f(b+\tau_n)|>\epsilon \tag{3}$$
Since $a+\tau_n\to\infty$ and $b+\tau_n \to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$, it follows that $\lim_{x\to\infty }f(x)$ does not exist.